# External connection to Postgres 9.5 connection refused

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I have following environment:

1. Ubuntu Trusty 14.04
2. Postgresql 9.5
3. IP Address 192.168.42.2

This environment was set up in VirtualBox.
The SSH connection to the guest system was successfully.
There was no firewall installed, so all ports are open.
I have executed the following configuration steps:

1. In `/etc/postgresql/8.2/main/pg_hba.conf` append line:

   ```
   host all all * md5
   ```
2. In `/etc/postgresql/8.2/main/postgresql.conf` modify line to:

   ```
   listen_addresses='*'
   ```
3. `/etc/init.d/postgresql restart`
4. Test Client:

   ```
   psql -h 192.168.42.2 -U postgres -d test
   ```

   result:

   ```
   psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "192.168.42.2" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   ```

I have no idea, what I have to do. Maybe Postgresql 9.5 needs a different configuration to 9.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

- If you ssh to the box, login or su as postgres, can you than connect with psql -d test? That would test whether postgresql is running correctly. If not, see if you can find it in `ps axf` (and do a `sudo service postgresql restart`)
- Above you refer to the "8.2" configuration tree. Perhaps you need to use the "9.5" tree? Easy to test with symlinks (ln -s 8.2 9.5)
- You can do a `telnet <your ip adres> <port>` to check whether you can reach the address and port in question from your host

Hope this helps,
Jeroen

Comment: thank you! your telnet tip was the solution. Normally postgres is listening on port 5432, but now it´s listening on port 5433. I don't know why, but it works ^^